# globalmenu doesn't work after installing gnome-shell

Tags: unity

Menu in unity isn't looked like usual after installing gnome-shell. I have unitnstalled gnome-shell but it doesn't back. what should i do?. it's so ugly.

Comment: Can you give us a picture of it, or describe how it now looks?

Answer (score 2):

Reset unity--open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type this into it:

```
unity --reset &
```

If that won't help then try this

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

Comment: it didn't make any change. sorry i don't know how to upload a picture here, just imagine an earlier version of ubuntu without global menu. exactly like that.

Comment: @AlifF.S. edited the answer

Comment: sorry, but nothing happen. i wonder what gnome-shell have done in my pc..